# Docker s390x tomcat image is giving fileupload error when deployed on OpenShift

Tags: docker, tomcat, openshift, redhat-openjdk, s390x

I have created a image using s390x/tomcat-9.0-jre8. I am trying to deploy these image on OpenShift zCX but it does not allow my application to upload files. I did checked the logs of tomcat but couldn't find anything that is of concern. When trying to Upload files, the error shown on UI is "Upload cancelled an error has occurred".

Image reference : https://hub.docker.com/layers/s390x/tomcat/9-jre8/images/sha256-687080725f53e7860eb1a51135b2067be3e408bfe5540013c09e3437c0bdc1a3?context=explore

I have few doubts :
As IBM supports zCX container on RedHat. Is it mandatory to have Open-JDK based image only. Or can we use any other java like JAVA_DEBIAN.

Are there any such issues reported before with these image?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that particular image, but if you are going to upload files you are going to have to configure some sort of persistent storage even if it is only `emptyDir`.

I'm not certain of what "support" IBM provides for zCX. (i.e. if this came from Red Hat they would take support calls on everything from the developer experience, through the operating system and JDK, the container runtime, and OpenShift. But IBM? I'm not sure.)

But there isn't anything about the container runtime that would cause any problems with a different JDK or a different OS.  What IBM "supports" may vary. i.e. I doubt they would actually provide support for a third-party container, but they *probably* would support the container runtime itself.

Which is probably relevant here. The execution of the container seems to be fine, but there is something wrong in your configuration of the persistent storage.

Comment: I have provided, the persistent storage. It works fine, when I take latest image of tomcat with jre11 for s390x.

Comment: I'd note that the image you linked is five years old. I'd strongly recommend using something newer for security reasons. Although there is no requirement to use Red Hat's version of Tomcat, I don't know why you wouldn't. That way you not only know it's OpenShift compatible but also that it is updated and secure.